# Heroku deployment issue - can you help me find the error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

My app works perfectly locally but on deployment it crashes. My Heroku log is below, i've already fixed a few issues but am now struggling to find the culprit. I'm aware of the Devise warnings, however, I can't see these being the cause....

Can anyone spot the offending error?

```
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:10:48+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-04-13T09:10:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-13T09:10:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-04-13T09:10:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2012-04-13T09:10:49+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2012-04-13T09:10:58+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rails server -p 48016`
2012-04-13T09:11:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:101: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-04-13T09:11:08+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.2/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:101: warning: already initialized constant PDF
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.case_insensitive_keys is false which is no longer supported. If you want to continue running on this mode, please ensure you are not using validatable (you can copy the validations directly to your model) and set case_insensitive_keys to an empty array.
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.use_salt_as_remember_token is false which is no longer supported. Devise now only uses the salt as remember token and the remember_token column can be removed from your models.
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: [DEVISE] Devise.reset_password_within is nil. Please set this value to an interval (for example, 6.hours) and add a reset_password_sent_at field to your Devise models (if they don't have one already).
2012-04-13T09:11:09+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.2 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48016
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/press.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.2/lib/active_record/base.rb:1088:in `method_missing': undefined method `to' for #<Class:0x00000005f87690> (NoMethodError)
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/app/models/press.rb:2:in `<class:Press>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:348:in `require_or_load'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:302:in `depend_on'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in `require_dependency'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:417:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `each'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:416:in `block in eager_load!'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `each'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/engine.rb:414:in `eager_load!'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:4:in `block in <main>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `new'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:46:in `app'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:54:in `block in <top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `tap'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:49:in `<top (required)>'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `require'
2012-04-13T09:11:13+00:00 app[web.1]:   from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
2012-04-13T09:11:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2012-04-13T09:11:14+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2012-04-13T09:11:17+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET gentle-lightning-5246.herokuapp.com/ dyno= queue= wait= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Looks like an error in your Press model. Also have you set "config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false" as per https://github.com/plataformatec/devise

Comment: Damn, i'm not even using that model at the moment! I'll get rid and try again. Thanks!

Comment: No to the Devise pointer - will try that too!

Comment: Can you show models/press.rb line 2 please.

Comment: @JohnBeynon - I've ditched the press model for now as it's not being used. Also added the config line suggested by John P into my environments/production.rb file and I seem to be getting somewhere.....it's not running but I now get the "We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)" error. Logs seem to be fine now, so just need to suss this 500 error.

Comment: You need to add config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false in config/application.rb. It doesn't work in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: @CupraR_On_Rails you should write your suggestion as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false in config/application.rb. It doesn't work in config/environments/production.rb

Comment: (I'm just filling in CupraR_On_Rails' answer in the Answer box so this question stops appearing in the Unanswered Questions list. @CupraR_On_Rails, feel free to post your answer yourself and I will delete this post so you get the rep)